# Find the point where the greater growth rate surpasses the lesser one without graphing

Tags: computer-science, graphing-functions

I have 2 lines:

f(x) = 2010x^2 + 1388x

and

g(x) = x^3

What's the strategy for finding a x1 >= 0 where g(x) becomes greater than f(x) for all x >= x1?

If one DNE, how would I know?

Comment: Write out $f(x)=g(x)$, divide by $x$, solve the resulting quadratic equation.

Comment: I got roots 2010.69 and -0.69. So I guess I should take 2011 as x1.

Comment: x @A_for: Eeyup.